# how to configure warning message that similar to wampserver in uniform server

Tags: php, warnings, wampserver, uniform

How to configure the warning message that shows in picture below in uniform server?
This warning message is captured from wampserver.
Because it list down the tracing error details.

Thank you!

[image: wampserver warning message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That extension is xdebug. You can download it from [here](http://www.xdebug.org/download.php)